# Toggle display button not working in Angular with click()

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I've files named as server.component.ts and server.component.html.

My server.component.ts file looks like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  templateUrl: './server.component.html',
  styles : [
    `.online {color : white;
    }`]
})
export class ServerComponent {
  serverId : number= 10;
  serverStatus : string = 'offLine';
  paragraphName : 'Paragraph01';
  showSecret = false;
  log = [];

  constructor(){
    this.serverStatus = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'online' : 'offline';
  }

  getServerStatus(){
    return this.serverStatus;
    
  }
  getColor(){
    return this.serverStatus === 'online'? 'Green':'Red';
  }

  onToggleDisplay(){
    this.showSecret = !this.showSecret;
    this.log.push(this.log.length + 1);
  }
}
```

and server.component.html file looks like :

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" (click) = "onToggleDisplay()">Display Details</button>
<p *ngIf  ="showSecret">Secret Password = tuna</p>
<div *ngFor = "Let logItem of log ">{{ logItem }}</div>
```

I am trying to print log item which should return log after clicking on *Display Details* button.
But nothing's happening.

*I am new to Angular.*

Comment: use small letter for let =>  <div *ngFor = "let logItem of log ">{{ logItem }}</div>

Comment: It's a typo. `*ngFor="Let ...` should be `*ngFor="let ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify this line , there is no `Let`, its `let` (with small letters)

```
<div *ngFor = "let logItem of log ">{{ logItem }}</div>
```

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wjkgeg)

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing a ngFor, you should `let item of itens`. It's written `Let`. Maybe that is the problem

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary" (click) = "onToggleDisplay()">Display Details</button>
<p *ngIf  ="showSecret">Secret Password = tuna</p>
<div *ngFor = "let logItem of log ">{{ logItem }}</div>
```